# Use image tag inside the for loop in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have an array which has set of image names. I could print all the images by using `console.log` but unfortunately when I tried `<img/>` it didn't view images.

```
   for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
   const element = array[index];
   console.log(element)
     }
```

output of `console.log(element)`

```
DSC_0000038.jpg 
DSC_0000040.jpg 
DSC_0000039.jpg 
DSC_0000047.jpg 
DSC_0000045.jpg 
DSC_0000049.jpg 
DSC_0000042.jpg 
DSC_0000041.jpg
```

how to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you post the render method?

Comment: @DFord this is inside the render method

Comment: `render: (record3) =>{
                    for (let index = 0; index < record3.split(",").length; index++) {
                    const element = record3.split(",")[index];
                    console.log(element)
                    }
                    
                }`

Comment: have you referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054512/react-img-tag-issue-with-url-and-class

Comment: no sir..thank you I'll check

Comment: @DFord it only print one image. I want to print all images

Comment: You shoud do something like: `return array.map((image, index) => <img src={image} key={index} />)`. Note that you should not use index as a key, but it's just for the sake of this example, to show you that you should put key prop here. (It should be some unique id of the image). Without this prop, you'll get react error saying: `Each child in array or iterator should have unique "key" prop`.

Comment: @PiotrSzlagura thank you sir.. It's working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
    import React from 'react'

    const myImages = [
    "DSC_0000038.jpg",
    "DSC_0000040.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000039.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000047.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000045.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000049.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000042.jpg", 
    "DSC_0000041.jpg"
    ]


    export default class Images extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          path : '/img/'
        }
      }

      render(){

        const images = myImages.map(
          (image, index) => <img src={this.state.path + image} key={index} alt="image" />
        )

        return(

          <section>
            {images}
          </section>

        )
      }

    }
```